# MySql on duplicate key set last_insert_id is causing auto_increment to jump

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment, on-duplicate-key

I have a query that goes as follows:

```
insert into TABLE(COLUMNS) values(VALUES) on duplicate key update id=last_insert_id(id)
```

I use this to get an ID of inserted or existing row of data.

```
$id=$connection->lastinsertid();
```

Well now I have a issue with my `auto_increment` jumping with each duplicate key update.

[image]

I am fairly certain `on duplicate key` update part is causing these jumps. Is this the source of the problem? Is there a way to fix this within the query without reseting `auto_increment` entirely every time?

Comment: What is a value of [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) settings on your MySql server ?

Comment: 1.) The autoincrement is not designed to be consecutive, but to be unique. It doesn't reset on failure (even without `on duplicate key`) or rollbacks. If you need consecutive numbers, you have to provide them (e.g. 2nd table which stores ids) 2.) `last_insert_id()` is not specific to that table, but returns the last autoincrement used in ANY table in your whole system. 3.) It's not clear what you are trying to do. I guess you want to get a correct id if someone tries to insert with an existing id. But this will update the *existing* row with a new id, not insert a new row with a corrected id.

Comment: 4.) If your intention is to get the id no matter if it exists or not, you should do it another way: first check if the row already exists: `select id from table ... <insert your duplicate key conditions, e.g. "where id = $id or name = '$name'" if you have a unique key on "name" and the pk>` (but with prepares statements, this is just pseudo code). If it finds a row, you have your id, otherwise insert and use `lastinsertid`. This will actually even reduce the number of failed attempts/on duplicate key-updates, so give you more consecutive numbers (apart from rollbacks).

Comment: What did you learn in your research?

Comment: I didn't look much into it. I reset my auto_increment before my insert to prevent the keys from jumping

Comment: @MatthewSemik I wonder what would be the performance trade-off if you reset the auto_increment just before every insert?